# DD-WRT DNSMasq Stops working when advanced options entered

Tags: dd-wrt, dnsmasq

I used the suggested version for my router and the latest beta and in both cases with Local DNS enabled, Used Domain Set to Lan AND WLAN and domain set accordingly everything works fine.

However I want to enter some Additional DNSMasq options. Namely expand-hosts and a few addresses for the internal network.

As soon as I put anything in this field and apply changes, it stops working.

Any ideas of what's going on here and how to get around this?

Thanks!